# How to reject specify HTML tags by using css or xpath selector

Tags: javascript, css, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I want to remove `style` and `script` tags and the contents of them by using css or xpath selector.

This is a example HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
      // style
    </style>
    <script>
      /* some script */
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>text</p>
    <script>
      /* some script */
    </script>
    <div>foo</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to get a HTML like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>text</p>
    <div>foo</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I thought I can get HTML that doesn't including `<script>` tags with this code, but somehow the code only duplicate the HTML.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("foo.text"))
doc.css(":not(script)").to_html
```

How can I enable the behavior I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler is just:

```
doc.search('style,script').remove
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these lines:

```
doc.search('.//style').remove
doc.search('.//script').remove
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's up to the OP to select the answer that best fits their needs. They have the option of changing their selection for a short while. Being first means nothing, being the better answer in the mind of the OP is what is important.